# How can I create internal user using my custom module in odoo15?

Tags: odoo-15

I don't want to use 'users' menu item and want to manage users from another menu item named 'Merchant' and only a specific user group data will be there and while creating new record I want to set a specific user_group. Is there any approach for that?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can simply add the menu directly under your module. Get the menu for `res.users` and put where ever you want. Don't forget to add dependency to `base`.
2. While doing that you can add a `domain` to the menu item and filter according to your needs.
3. Also put that `domain` into the `context` of the menu with giving a default value same as the `domain`. That is, you need to put the required settings in the `context` like `{default_FIELD_NAME: VALUE}`. You need to use the `default_` prefix for it to work. That way when creating a new user from your menu the `context` will get the default value and set accordingly. However, if it is not a readonly field, user may change the value. There are two ways to avoid that:
   i. create your own form using the `res.users` and design it the way you like it with default values.
   ii. inherit the view of `res.users` and change the related field to be readonly if a certain context value is passed. Then you can call the view with context let's say `{readonly_group_x: True}` and it should work. Also you may need to make sure that `force_save="1"` is set since it may not save the readonly field.

These are the basic steps of accomplishing what you have described. However, working with `res.groups` can be challenging depending on what you want to do. You may need to tweak or even end up creating your own view with the desired effect.